# What happen if two transaction with different isolation level access same table

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level

I am using PostgreSQL.

If I have a table, and two transactions, each of them have different isolation level access the table, what would happen?

Just for some background context: I have one "speed" request, which only modify 1 row of data, so I use "read committed" isolation for the transaction. The other request, which is a long running process, is using serialize-snapshot-isolation (SSI). Which isolation will the DB honor?

Comment: Access the table in what way? Reading or writing?

Comment: Both have "write" access.